# Store font of button in the constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a customized button deriving from System.Windows.Forms.Button:

```
(class MyButton : Button)
```

This button has an extra property called IsSelected.

```
public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;

            if (value)
                this.Font = new Font(_storedFont.FontFamily, _storedFont.Size - 1); //Decrease font size by 1
            else
                this.Font = _storedFont; //Set font back to origin

        }
    }
```

If IsSelected is set true the font size of the button will be decreased by 1 point to show the user of the application, that this button is in "pressed" state. 
If IsSelected is set false the font size of the button will be set back to original size to show the user that this button is now again in "normal" state.

The issue is now that I first need to store the original font size that has been set in the properties window in Visual Studio, before it is changed by IsSelected.

To hold the stored original font size I have property called StoredFont (class level field = _storedFont).

I then tried to store the original font size in a chained constructor in MyButton, but it appears that the constructor is called before Visual Studio has actually set the font that has been defined in the properties window.

**Question 1:**
Is it correct that the constructor is called before Visual Studio actually sets the font?

**Question 2:**
Any suggestions to how to save the font that has been set from the properties window when a new instance of MyButton is created?

**Note!**
I have already considered many other possibilities to show selected state (CheckBox instead of Button, other back color etc.), and this is not my question.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Just curious. Are you using your own/custom button format class?

Comment: I just created a new class deriving from Button, and then added some extra properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** Yes otherwise you'll endup with a NullReferenceException...

**Question 2:** Assuming the first Font assignment is the font you want to store, you could store the font in an override of Font

```
    public override Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Font;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_storedFont == null)
                 _storedFont = Font;

            base.Font = value;
        }
    }
```

This way you don't have to worry about the order of initialization.